# How do I get the "Add Controller" and "Add View" menu options in my ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I added ASP.NET MVC manually to an existing WebForms application... thanks to 
[this tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc).

However, now I do not have the menu options (When right-clicking on the Controllers folder or Views folders) to show the Add Controller or Add View dialog boxes.  I do have this when creating a brand new MVC project.  How can I get visual studio to realize I am using MVC in this mixed project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically controllers are just .CS files that are put in the controllers folder and views are just .ASPX files that are put in the views folder.  Your controllers classes need to inherit from the base Controller class and your ASPX page needs to inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.

As far as getting those items in your menu though try opening your project file and replacing the projecttypeguids tag with this one.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: This worked for me; except the `projecttypeguid` was `{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}`. 

I copied this from an existing MVC application that worked.  I suspect that it is just due to a different version of MVC.

Comment: Probably, I suspect this was around MVC2 when I answered the above.

Comment: I used the VS2013 RC to play around with MVC5 then shipped back the soluton to VS2012 once the trial ran out. I kept MVC5 projects since they integrate very nicely with bootstrap etc but when switching back to VS2012 had same problem as OP. So for my scenario, MVC 5 in VS2013, to MVC 4 IN VS2012 the project typeguids that got my scaffolding options back were: {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

Comment: I have Visual studio 2015 Enterprise. those keys are not working for my MVC 4 application. It showing me Goto View but now showing Create View on Controller Action Context menu.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix your machine, go to the URL at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532 and make sure you install both "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012" and "ASP.NET and Web Frameworks 2013.1 - Visual Studio 2012".

After installation you should have them both in your installed programs list.

For more details you can check this URL: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx.

The Project Type GUID thing is just a workaround. But it will automatically be removed after you install these.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same problem, except I started off cleanly with an Asp.Net MVC project. Don't know why this is happening. While I realize full well what controllers are(Harv) I still desire the auto-generation that the context-senstive menu options offer. CS menu's are not appearing in Solution Explorer or in the document window when editing the controller file, according to Walther video, he simply right-clicks on the Index method and he gets a cs menu option to create a view, an Add View dialog window. Oh BTW, my project guids are identical to the ones you provided, so that didn't help.

Thanks, 
Berlioz

Answer (score 1):

Do nothing just update your MVC project version. Fire this command in your Nuget Package Manager console.

> Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Restart your visual studio project.

Also don't forgot this.
For resolving this error

> Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()'

Install-Package -Id  Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 update1 and was resolved by installing the latest update.

Answer (score -4):

ASP.NET MVC prefers convention over configuration so there's really no way other than Harv's answer to be able to set it up.  You have to right-click a folder named Controllers and a folder named Views to get those options.