# Context menu to Add Controller/View missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I have integrated ASP.NET MVC 4 into existing asp.net web site.  Both works fine but I don't see any menu/shortcuts to create controller/view within visual studio IDE.  Are those only available to ASP.NET MVC template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the "Add Controller" and "Add View" menu options in my ASP.NET MVC project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811510/how-do-i-get-the-add-controller-and-add-view-menu-options-in-my-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> Are those only available to ASP.NET MVC template?

Yes, but you could cheat. The way Visual Studio shows those shortcuts is by looking at the project type and if it sees that it is an ASP.NET MVC project it will make them available. But how does it know it is an ASP.NET MVC project? After all ASP.NET MVC is an ASP.NET project.

Open the `.csproj` file and look for the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` node of your ASP.NET MVC 4 project. You will see something like this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Now open the `.csproj` file of your regular ASP.NET project and simply add the `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}` GUID as first item in the list (if you don't project does not even load). That's all. Now you will see the ASP.NET MVC specific context menus in your WebForms project.

Comment: I don't know. What happened when you tested it?

Comment: You have to add the new GUID as the first item for this to work apparently (else it can't load the project).

Comment: Is there a possiblity to use these menu items in Portable Area Projects? Commands show up but VS cannot find proper views/controllers because they are residing in common directory instead of being placed directly in project dir.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. FYI, to edit .csproj from within VS2012 unload the project, right-click on project name and select "Edit .csproj"

Comment: Just to throw it out there - On VS2013 I was able to solve this problem by unloading the project and then reloading the project. -i.e. I didn't have to mess around with the ProjectTypeGuids.

Comment: Yes in VS2013 the ProjectTypeGuid, {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}, is not needed for the context menus. But NOTE WELL that this applies to a Web Application and not a Web Site project.  You can tell the difference because the Web Site lacks *.aspx.designer.cs files.  I recommend converting the Web Site to a Web Application project for best compatibility with hybrid MVC and Web Forms.

Comment: worked for me, but I first needed to install this update:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401} worked for me, but {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47} did not

Comment: When I modify the .csproj file, and add the GUID, then reload the project, Visual Studio removes the GUID. I'm assuming that Visual Studio thinks the GUID is invalid, which is why it decides to remove it. I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I added {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47} to <ProjectTypeGuids> but now when I try to begin the project Visual studio 2013 say I can´t begin the project since a class library

Comment: @wodzu Thankyou, this was just what I needed.
I also realized that although I am still unable to get "add controller" directly in the first prompt, I can get what I need by doing "add" >  "new item... " > "MVC4 Controller Class".  Problem solved.

Comment: I have multiple class library projects , when i make changes as mentioned i get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565528/visual-studio-needs-to-make-non-functional-changes-to-this-project) error ?

Comment: I have tried many solution but not worked this one is Perfect and easily done 
Thank you @DarinDimitrov

Answer (score 33):

Step to change the GUID

1. Right click on the project in solution explorer
2. Click unload project
3. Right click again on the project in solution explorer
4. Edit projectfolder/projectname.csproj
5. Chagne GUID
6. Right click and select "Reload Project"

In `<ProjectTypeGuids>` tag add any of these GUIDs in beginning

```
{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};

{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 `{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}` worked for me, but `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}` did not

Comment: you need to check http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Comment: For MVC5 you need to add: {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};

Comment: I have multiple class library projects , when i make changes as mentioned i get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565528/visual-studio-needs-to-make-non-functional-changes-to-this-project) error ?

Comment: There wasn't a guid in there for me

Answer (score 9):

For people using MVC 5, add this key

```
{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};
```

in the beginning of . The other guids won't work.

Comment: Worked for me in vs 2012 with MVC5

Answer (score 8):

Do nothing just update your MVC project. Fire this command in your Nuget Package Manager console.

> Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: Worked for me.  Changing the GUID didn't help (I already had the MVC 4 GUID in my project).

Answer (score 3):

Answer 2 was correct just wrong guid

> {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}

is what you need for MVC in VS2010

Comment: Hi Don.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  The order answers appear on a page isn't guaranteed (it changes by rank, by default), so referencing a post by # can be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

By right clicking the project in Solution Explorer, you need to unload the project, edit the project, change the  tag using the chart below, and then reload the project. 
Paste the appropriate GUID to the front of the list in the csproj file.

The different GUIDs for different versions of MVC:

```
ASP.NET MVC 1   {603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0}
ASP.NET MVC 2   {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
ASP.NET MVC 3   {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}
ASP.NET MVC 4   {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
ASP.NET MVC 5   {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when opened MVC project as Web Site. I reopened solution thru Open -> Project and this functionality worked as I expected.

Comment: Please give some more details, if you're able.  Brief answers are acceptable, but the better answers have much more detail than this.  See StackOverflow's [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just ran into this switching between VS2013 and VS2012 for an MVC 5 Project.  The issue I had is that the version of the MVC Template I was using wasn't installed from the Visual Studio update.  VS2012 didn't come with MVC5 as it came out after it, so an update was required for VS2012 to add the template.  Same with VS2010 and MVC4 I imagine.

Anyhow, downloading the update from Microsoft resolved my issue as when another version opened and saved the project, it would again disappear when using the fix above.

Here is the link to the VS2012 MVC5 update.  Ensure that you download and install both the Tools update and the VS plugin.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532

Answer (score 1):

For me it was missing from where I expected it to exist (at the top of the menu which shows when you right click on a view folder and click on 'Add'), but then I found it at a sub context menu under 'New From Template'! I have re-sharper installed, I guess it happened because of it (Also Visual Studio 2012):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with **VS2015**, helped changing ProjectTypeGuids content to:

```
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
```

Comment: which file did you change?

Comment: I changed .csproj file

Answer (score 1):

I am on VS2012 and tried Dimitrov's answer (adding a particular GUID to the project file's ProjectTypeGuids). While this did give me the missing context menu for the controller actions, I was missing intellisense on my Razor pages.

It turns out I was missing the VS tooling for the version of the MVC project I was working on, and installing this tooling (rather than editing the project file) resolved my issues.

[Download page for ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532)

I found this download link from the following blog post:

[Announcing release of ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The presence of these context menu options is project type/template specific.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Is there any plug-in available to take advantage of MVC in ASP.NET web forms app?

Comment: @StormeHawke I disagree, it directly answers the above question: "Are those only available to ASP.NET MVC template?".

Answer (score 0):

For older version

```
{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
```

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails (before reinstalling VS2015) you might want to reset VS cache.  This worked for me (after repairing - NOT meddling with GUIDS).  Just delete the contents in the folders mentioned in this link (takes about 30 seconds), then execute the command.  That takes another 10 seconds.  Restart VS and you will see the screens of a first-time user in VS.  It worked like a charm.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also occur when you have just checked out a fresh copy of your solution from your code repository and the NuGet packages, including Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, have not yet been downloaded. Rebuilding the solution fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me with VS 2017.

First check if you're able to create a new empty MVC project.

If not - this means some components are missing. Launch Visual Studio Installer (typicall sits in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe` but you cna just hit "start" and start typing "visual studio installer")

Lick "modify" and simply re-run it with all existing components checked.

Just make sure "ASP.NET Web development" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You might have opened the project as folder type which limits the visual studio IDE to limit certain GUID options, so load your project solution.

It should work. Add view or Add controller should be available as soon as you right click on the ActionResult or inside controller.

Answer (score -2):

VS2012 Context menu to Add Controller/View missing

In VS2012 & MVC4 try unistall Web API 5.2 in PM:

```
UnInstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
```