# Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2010

I opened a C# project that was created in VS 2010 SP, with VS 2012. A one-way conversion window appeared where I proceeded with the conversion.

Upon completion I got the following warning:

> Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in
>   order to enable the project to open in this version and Visual Studio
>   2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior.

...but it doesn't say *which* non-functional changes. Can someone clue me in?

Comment: Fairly fresh bug report to MS [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772032/uncorrected-migration-from-vs2010-to-vs2012) regarding that message.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm unsure as to why exactly this happens but I found that after first opening a VS2010 SharePoint 2010 project in VS2012 amongst other changes the following nodes were added to the .csproj file:

```
<ProjectMode>SharePointCustomization</ProjectMode>
<TargetOfficeVersion>15.0</TargetOfficeVersion>
<FileUpgradeFlags>0</FileUpgradeFlags>
<UpgradeBackupLocation>blah\blah\blah</UpgradeBackupLocation>
<OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
```

I found that if I manually edited the csproj file and removed the following three nodes the next time I opened the project no upgrade logs opened and the issue was resolved:

```
<FileUpgradeFlags>0</FileUpgradeFlags>
<UpgradeBackupLocation>blah\blah\blah</UpgradeBackupLocation>
<OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing the content of the nodes 'FileUpgradeFlags', 'OldToolsVersion' in the .csproj File solves the Problem.

```
<FileUpgradeFlags></FileUpgradeFlags>
<OldToolsVersion></OldToolsVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the .csproj file, you will see this:

```
< Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props"     

 Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

and

```
< OldToolsVersion>4.0< /OldToolsVersion>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why this is an answer to the question?

Comment: I have since revised my decision.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from **True** to **False**

```
<SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>True</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>

<SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, removing the following 2 settings elements in the project file that was triggering the upgrade fixed the problem:

Child element of *Project/PropertyGroup*:

```
<ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
```

Child element of *Project*:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem in VS2013 in a big multi project via opening the .csproj file and changing this

```
<FileUpgradeFlags>
</FileUpgradeFlags>
```

like this

```
<FileUpgradeFlags></FileUpgradeFlags>
```