# How can I complete the build of fltk 1.1.10 in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, fltk

I am trying to build fltk 1.1.10 in Visual Studio 2013 but I get the warning

"fltk.sln: Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior."

After searching, I found out how to do this for a C# project but how can I do it for fltk.sln?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 solutions in the FLTK1.1.10 distribution

- visualc - for Visual Studio 6
- vcnet - for Visual Studio 2003
- vc2005 - for Visual Studio 2005

None of these will load directly into VS2013.  They have to be converted to VS2013 format.  Easiest way is to make a copy of vc2005 and call it vc2013.  Then start fltk.sln.  It will tell you that it needs to make a one way upgrade with the message you described.  Just click OK.

What this does is migrate the 2005 sln to 2013 sln and migrate the vcproj files to vcxproj files.  Basically you don't lose the vcproj files - you just get completely new versions of vcxproj files.  Once that is done, just do a build.

Comment: That's how I got the warning. I opened fltk.dsw from visualc and upgraded it. The warning message came after the migration. It did build successfully though and the files became .vcxproj.

I tried your copy and rename folder suggestion with all three and I get the same message.

I found this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565528/visual-studio-needs-to-make-non-functional-changes-to-this-project, which seems to suggest that I need to change something in the .vcxproj. But I've no idea what or how to do this with fltk.dsw/fltk.sln. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: I've just tried it on visualc.  Not getting the message after migration.