# No Add Controller on menu and can't add a View either in MVC 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I just downloaded the new nopCommerce 3.2 MVC 4 application.
When I open the solution in Visual Studio,
I can't add a Controller : there is no "Controller...." option from the "Add" menu.
There is also no "Add View" when I right click inside of a Controller.

It seems to be treating all the projects in the solution as "Web Forms".

I think is has something to do with the last Windows update. It changed something.
I have the latest updates on Visual Studio.

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this?
Thanks

**UPDATE : Solved. Need to install this update :**

[ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012][1] : [1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Have you installed MVC 4?

Comment: nopCommerce 3.2 uses ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: I can add a "MVC 4 application" on the new project menu.
On the nopCommerce properties page, it shows .NET 4.5 version.
Should I download MVC 5? thanks

Comment: I just tried to download .NET 4.5 but got "Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer." How can I tell if my application is using MVC 5?

Answer (score 9):

You need to add {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47} as 'the first GUID' to  in your project .csproj. You may not need to update your Visual Studio.

Refer to [Context menu to Add Controller/View missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing)

Comment: Slight oddity: the GUID needs to be in all lowercase.

Comment: Read the link, still don't understand. Can you explain what 'the first GUID' means for users new to Visual Studio and asp.net? I've found the .csproj, but not understanding what first GUID means.

Answer (score -2):

Just two steps

1)Update your Visual studio 2013

2) unload your project from solution explorer then Reload it again.

Comment: The OP does not need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2013 to work with MVC 5 - the updates cited in the question update are however required for MVC 5.

Comment: This was not helpful. Without modifying the project type GUIDs ( I used a blank project for an API, but ended up need admin pages and such ) this doesn't do anything.

Comment: But believe this is still work for me until I upgrade VS2013 to latest Update.