# Add view in MVC in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, view

Can someone please help me. I created function that will list my data on my database. And as I right clicked on the actionresult i can't seem to find the "add view" option. Is there anything I should fix in the settings in visual studio?

[image]

Comment: Try creating a Hello World app and note how the right-click menu shows on this page: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-view

Comment: there is still no add view.

Comment: Make sure you have latest version of ASP.NET tools and visual studio, see here like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497808/no-add-controller-on-menu-and-cant-add-a-view-either-in-mvc-4-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. It turns out that the packages I have for MVC was just outdated. Just right click on the project and click Manage NuGet Packages and update the outdated packages.

Answer (score 0):

Does the class containing your function inherit from Controller?  You only get that option if the method is inside a controller class.

E.g. it should look like this:

```
public class Test2Controller: Controller
{
    // GET: Test2
    public ActionResult YourFunction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you remove the ':Controller' bit you will see you no longer get the Add View option.