# Unable to add Razor view to project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I can't add razor view to MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2017.
There just doesn't seem to be the template

[image]

As you can see if I choose Web from template list nothing is visible and all I see is *Please choose a project type*.
Now this is puzzling as I've seen [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497808/no-add-controller-on-menu-and-cant-add-a-view-either-in-mvc-4-5) where both of them suggest to set project type GUID in **.csproj**.

I do have it set and it was there (I didn't add anything)

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Looking at the [list of GUIDs](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs) it seems that the first GUID suggests that this is ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

I also checked VS2017 installation and I do have web tooling installed

[image]

Any clue what I can also try to enable adding web templates to project?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add a new project to a solution or a new item to a project? Its not clear in your question?

Within your project (Solution Explorer), try right click on the Views Folder, choose add, New Item and see if you can find anything there?

Comment: I'm trying to add a **new item** - namely razor view. Unfortunately, there is nothing when I try to add new item (see first screenshot in my original post), hence my post here.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did :) along with clearing VS component cache and all cache related things I could find.