# Visual Studio Project Reload Removes Added ProjectType GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

All over the internet and even here on SO, it is suggested to add a GUID to the project file ProjectType list of GUIDs if the scaffolding menu options for creating an MVC controller are missing. It's also not even an available template when just doing a plain "add item".

Here's where that's mentioned on SO:
[Context menu to Add Controller/View missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing)

So I add that GUID then reload the project at which point Visual Studio decides to remove that it automatically without any notifications. It's just annoying not having the scaffolding for MVC controllers although I know I can create them manually. I **do** have the scaffolding for Web API controllers as well as MVC views. In the web project I'm using MVC 4 and Web API 2.2.

This is happening on a fully updated VS2012 with web tools 2013.1 install as well as a fully updated VS2013. However, on a colleagues VS2012 install adding the GUID works and reloading the project doesn't remove it.

The only thing I can think of is that on my VS2012 install I have MVC 5 and Web API 2.2 support installed (I think through web tools 2013.1?) and that's causing some sort of compatibility issue with VS.

**Why is this happening and how do I fix it?**

Here's a screen capture of some of the .NET things I have installed if it helps:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add that Project Type GUID. This is only a workaround, but it will be removed automatically if you open the project on a machine having ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013 for Visual Studio 2012 installed.

So, in order to fix your machine, go to the URL at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532 and make sure you install both "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012" and "ASP.NET and Web Frameworks 2013.1 - Visual Studio 2012":

[image: if you have VS Express choose 1 and 3, else choose 1 and 2]

After installation you should have these both in your installed programs list:

[image: after installation]

For more details you can check this URL: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Odd. I downloaded both of those items and began the installations. Each was already installed but I ran a "repair" anyway. Still no luck. I'll update my question with a screen capture of all the things installed in that area.

Comment: Well, this worked on my side. And I had the exact same scenario: I was adding the GUID, Check In into TFS, then after a while Get Latest Version from TFS and GUID was removed. And this happened because my colleagues had these tools installed. After I installed them (I only used to had the "Web Frameworks" installed) all seems to be OK (no GUID needed, context menu will always display correctly).

Comment: in my case the GUID isn't disappearing from someone else's check-in. When I reload the project, visual studio removes it.

Comment: @MikeHaas And you don't have the MVC context menus? For me VS started removing the GUID only after I fixed the issue and context menus appeared.