# Mixing MVC and Webforms - Displaying BOTH Context Menus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have added MVC4 to an ASP.NET Webforms project in Visual Studio 2010.

I changed the .csproj's project type to that of an MVC4 project as detailed here:
[Context menu to Add Controller/View missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing)
to give me the MVC specific context menus.

Now the ASP.NET Webforms context menus (such as add 'UserControl') are gone.

How can I hack VS2010 to give me both the MVC4 and ASP.NET context menus for a given project?

Comment: By "ASP.NET" do you mean webforms?

Comment: Yes plain Webforms project

Comment: I am not sure if that can be done at all as you are dealing with different project types. What's the problem in adding controllers and views manually?

Answer (score 3):

In short and officially: no, this is not possible (disclaimer: I'm a software engineer at Microsoft who used to work on Visual Studio + Blend, but now Internet Explorer).

In Visual Studio, a project only has a single type, and the "ASP.NET Web Application" (WebForms) and "ASP.NET MVC Application" (ASP.NET MVC) are two different project types - they're very similar and share common features, but are still different types.

The MVC project type does not have UserControls and other Items in the Add New Item dialog or context-menus because they're largely irrelevant and wouldn't work as you expect them to (granted, it is possible to have WebForms (and not just using `.aspx` files as Views)) but I don't think it's a good application-design decision.

Unofficially... the items that appear in the Add New Item dialog are specified in the registry. This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165141.aspx however this information is intended for developers of new project types, rather than allowing users to modify their own (and certainly you're at risk of breaking your VS if we release another update which makes assumptions about how your Add New Item templates are configured).

If you want to do it this way - go ahead, but be careful, and make a note of everything you do so you can undo it.

Comment: Thanks for the information!  So a solution could be to create a new ProjectType in the registry with both the MVC and WebForms new item templates present.  Then manually change the existing CSPROJ to the new type.  This would not break existing project types and could be backed out of.

Comment: Just for information, does Visual Studio use the project type when compiling?  Or just the file type?

Comment: @divinci Creating a new ProjectType in the registry won't work: a project type (and its GUID) is actually defined in compiled code and the registry key is just a reference to this existing-defined GUID. Instead, I was suggesting that you add the WebForms Item Templates to the MVC Item Templates list, so you can retain WebForm's Item Templates in MVC projects.

Comment: @divinci What do you mean by "File Type"?

Answer (score 0):

Since the IDE is based on working in single mode, It seems we have 2 ways:

1. Attempt to use a configuration that is done an `OR` action between two project types, so we have both of them, but lack of true functionality is demanded :(
2. Write some lines of C++ code to change configuration immediately (based on tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing)), so you have a switcher application to run when you want :)

Comment: Long shot - would it be possible to run the one (perhaps MVC) project on a sub-domain and use jQuery AJAX to call in the elements needed to your webforms project? This obviously depends on the site's respective setups. I'm thinking you could `inject` MVC elements into your aspx pages

Comment: @scgough You're true :). But problem is about IDE, not on server!

Comment: Ah yes, I see. So close! I thought I had 500 pts in the bag ;-)

Comment: @scgough :)))) Perhaps, What do you think? sometimes such this mistakes cause to solve!