# VS doesn't show "Create View" option in the popup menu

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2013.

I create a new method in my controler but when try to create the view only say **Go To View** instead of **Create View**.

[image]

And that say produce this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(**Go To View**) does not create view it will navigate you to a view of the same name of the action. To Add a view for this action, then choose to (**Add View**) *you can find it below (Go To View) in the same menu*.

Comment: I know that. The problem is the `Add View` option  doesnt appear. :(

Comment: I update the picture so is more obvious the option isnt there

Comment: These options are only available to ASP.NET MVC template. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing