# Missing add view/go to view in my VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

the add view and other menus are missing.

[image]

I already tried fixing my GUID as said in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing)

but it didn't work for me. Any ideas?

I noticed that everytime I close a project. Those menus will go missing when I reopen them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer is for VS2012 and mvc 4. You are probably using MVC5 or mvc-core, so the GUID should be different. Please try this:

Create a new project, of the version you are targeting. Check the GUID. Copy it to your csproj file.

...and let us know if it works!

Comment: still missing the menus after taking the GUID from a new project

Comment: @chemical_elii I am really interested in this: what steps did you take exactly to create your project? I want to recreate the issue

Comment: so while I was taking the screenshots. I noticed that if I use open folder, this problem occurs, so I tried using open project. The options in the menus are back again. Still curious why this happens?

Comment: @chemical_elii Heh...this opens your files to view and edit, but does not load project options! That was obvious...still, this question may help some ppl out there!!