# MVC Add Area and Controller Options are missing from Context menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using Visual studio 2013 and after opening an existing project, I am not able to see the add Controller or Area option.

[Context menu to Add Controller/View missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing)

I have tried this question answer but it’s not worked for me

Then I added a new project in that solution and in that project I found all missing options.
But in my main project they are still missing .

Comment: It sounds like the project guid is not correct. I think the menus are dependend on the type of project you have. If you add a new project which is an MVC project you will get those options. If it is a normal webforms project you don't have those options

Comment: i have opend this solution after a 1 month before this i am working fine on same vs2013 on same pc. it was also created on same vs2013

Comment: Still look at the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` please to be sure this isn't your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the project type guid 
and then search for the guid on [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)

1. You will find these properties as a `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element in the project file, not to be confused with `<ProjectGuid>` which is a unique identifier for your project.
2. Some GUIDs are used in combination. For example `<ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>` describes a Xamarin.Android library in C#.

Comment: can i change project <ProjectTypeGuids> and <ProjectGuid> from my new added project <ProjectTypeGuids> and <ProjectGuid>

Comment: @pramodmaurya dont change the projectguid

Comment: Can you Please give some more information. What is the projecttypeguid of the project for example?

Comment: i have tried another pc vs2013 same solution working fine and getting all missing options