# missing context menu in vs 2017 asp.net core 2.2 to add controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

The solutions discussed in [Context menu to Add Controller/View missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing) were not very helpful in my case.
I just started a new project with asp.net core mvc 2.2 using visual studio community 15.7.6 on windows 10 and applying the database first command. Now I want to add a controller but the "Controller" entry in the context menu of the solution explorer is missing. This issue does not occure in a project using asp.net core 2.1 in the same environment.

I tried unloading/reloading the project and the missing entry appears but when I click on it nothing happens. Next time I open the context menu the entry is gone again.
Also, I had a look into the csproj files but there are no ProjectTypeGuids:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What I am actually missing is this dialog:

Add scaffold dialog

[image: add scaffold dialog]

Any ideas what else I can try to fix this?

Comment: I believe they have never been there. You don't need it anyway. I find creating my own file is much faster and less hassle.

Comment: Add a new class and inherit from controller. Job done.

Comment: @Luke Vo The functionality I am missing is helpful when implementing crud functions. All the required methods and the according view structure are generated automatically. I think the issue must have something to do with entity framework.

Comment: I never find them to be actually useful. Especially when .NET Core tend to focus on SPA/Web API projects now.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved after updating VS 2017 to version 15.9.9

8-/

Answer (score 2):

Actually when you are downloading [.NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) you must take a look at required visual studio version.

[image: Required visual studio]

It is super important. If you create a project on a visual studio with lower required version you still can create it but it don't work properly.